# Is it bad practice in Java to modify input object in void method?

Tags: java

In Java, assume you have a data object `object` with an attribute `bar` that you need to set with a value that is returned from a complex operation done in an external source. Assume you have a method `sendRequestToExternalSource` that send a request based on 'object' to the external source and gets an object back holding (among other things) the needed value.

Which one of these ways to set the value is the better practice?

```
void main(MyObject object) {
    bar = sendRequestToExternalSource(object);
    object.setBar(bar);
}

String sendRequestToExternalSource(MyObject object) {

    // Send request to external source
    Object response = postToExternalSource(object);

    //Do some validation and logic based on response
    ...

    //Return only the attribute we are interested in
    return response.getBar();
}
```

or

```
void main(MyObject object) {
    sendRequestToExternalSourceAndUpdateObject(object);
}

void sendRequestToExternalSourceAndUpdateObject(MyObject object) {

    // Send request to external source
    Object response = postToExternalSource(object);

    //Do some validation and logic based on response
    ...

    //Set the attribute on the input object
    object.setBar(response.getBar());
}
```

I know they both work, but what is the best practice?

Comment: I guess it really depends on how you see your code evolving.  If you ever expect to have a use case where you _don't_ want that setter being called, then the first version would be preferable, since it returns the `bar` value, but leaves it up to the caller to decide what he wants to do with that return value.

Comment: In your second example the variable bar is undefined.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of the actual code? Like what's `barService`? Why do you want a separate method rather than an instance method / getter&setter on that object?

Comment: is it called `side effect`, and well, as far as I know it is not a bad practice, but it would be better for readability and understandability of the code, to avoid it, if you can.

Comment: Note that there are multiple examples where **side-effects** intuitively are to be expected and that's also totally fine. For example `Collections#sort` which sorts the given collection in-place without creating a new one for the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It **depends** on a **specific** scenario. **Side-effects** are **not bad practice** but there are also scenarios where a user simply won't expect them.

In any case your **documentation** of such a method should **clearly state** if you manipulate arguments. The user must be informed about that since it's *his* object that he passes to your method.

---

Note that there are various examples where **side-effects** intuitively are to be expected and that's also totally fine. For example `Collections#sort` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)):

```
List<Integer> list = ...
Collections.sort(list);
```

However if you write a method like `intersection(Set, Set)` then you would expect the result being a new `Set`, not for example the first one. But you can rephrase the name to `intersect` and use a structure like `Set#intersect(Set)`. Then the user would expect a method with `void` as return type where the resulting `Set` is the `Set` the method was invoked on.

Another example would be `Set#add`. You would expect that the method inserts **your element** and not a copy of it. And that is also what it does. It would be confusing for people if it instead creates copies. They would need to call it differently then, like `CloneSet` or something like that.

---

In general I would tend to giving the advice to **avoid** manipulating arguments. Except if *side-effects* are to be expected by the user, as seen in the example. Otherwise the risk is too high that you confuse the user and thus create nasty bugs.

Comment: Good answer, thanks! I updated the question code to be more like the real-world situation where this happens. Would it be enough to change the name of the method as I have in the new example code above to "...AndUpdateObject"? I guess it's "clearly stated in documentation" then, but it still just feels like bad practice to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose the first one if I have only these two choices. And the reason of that is "S" in [SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) principles, single responsibility. I think the job of `doComplicatedStuff` method is not setting new or enriched value of `bar` to `MyObject` instance.

Of course I don't know use case that you are trying to implement, but I suggest looking at [decorator pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-decorator) to modify `MyObject` instance

Comment: I think the 'S in SOLID' is exactly the reason I was looking for why one way feels better than the other. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the variant `barService.doComplicatedStuff(object);` because I avoid making copies

Comment: It's a good argument, could you (for the sake of a more complete argument) also clarify why copies are a bad thing?

Comment: Imagine you have a huge array or texture and you copy it each time.